# update carad set adminActivation = '%d' where carAdID = '1'

Tags: php, oop, sql-update

```
function UpdateStatus()
{
    $updateStatusStringBuilder = " update carad ";
    $updateStatusStringBuilder .= " set";
    $updateStatusStringBuilder .= " adminActivation = '%d'";
    $updateStatusStringBuilder .= " where ";
    return $updateStatusStringBuilder;
}
function UpdateStatusByAdminActivation($adminActivationStatus,$CarAdID)
{
    $this->connect();
    $CaradMappingQuery = new CaradMapping();
    $query = $CaradMappingQuery->UpdateStatus()." carAdID = '".mysql_real_escape_string($CarAdID)."'";
    echo $query;
    $this->iquery($query);
}
```

The query is not updating the result in database, I am bit confused about '%d', I am printing this value and its showing like below:

`update carad set adminActivation = '%d' where carAdID = '1'`

what i use instead of '%d' if I am wrong

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the value you want to set instead of `'%d'` like the Edit.

For dynamic value of %d you have to use `MySqli` and `PDO`. That query is known as `Prepared Statement`

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: but '%d' is dynamic, how i can get the dynamic value